# Fit data with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

i try to fit with Gnuplot the data in the joined data
i try to do fit with polynom a*x+b but there is not a good approximatoion.

So my question is please hwo we can choos f(x) to obtain a good approximation with fit?

i try to apply the demo in [enter link description here](http://gnuplot.info/demo_5.4/fit.html) but i don't understand how we choose the good function f

```
14 -1.51165
14 -1.47888
14 -1.44592
14 -1.41279
14 -1.37947
14 -1.34597
14 -1.31228
14 -1.2784
14 -1.24433
14 -1.21007
14 -1.17561
14 -1.14095
14 -1.1061
14 -1.07104
14 -1.03578
14 -1.00031
14 -0.964631
14 -0.928743
14 -0.892643
14 -0.856326
14 -0.819792
14 -0.783037
14 -0.746059
14 -0.708855
14 -0.671423
14 -0.63376
14 -0.595863
14 -0.55773
14 -0.519357
14 -0.480742
14 -0.441881
14 -0.402773
14 -0.363413
14 -0.323798
14 -0.283926
14 -0.243794
14 -0.203397
14 -0.162733
14 -0.121799
14 -0.0805896
14 -0.0308833
14 0.0436781
14 0.0934042
14 0.134646
14 0.17563
14 0.216359
14 0.256837
14 0.297066
14 0.337049
14 0.376791
14 0.416292
14 0.455558
14 0.49459
14 0.533391
14 0.571964
14 0.610311
14 0.648436
14 0.686341
14 0.724028
14 0.761501
14 0.798761
14 0.835811
14 0.872654
14 0.909291
14 0.945725
14 0.981959
14 1.01799
14 1.05383
14 1.08948
14 1.12493
14 1.16019
14 1.19527
14 1.23016
14 1.26486
14 1.29939
14 1.33373
14 1.36789
14 1.40188
14 1.4357
14 1.46934
14 1.50281
15 -3.49071
15 -3.47651
15 -3.46218
15 -3.4477
15 -3.43308
15 -3.41832
15 -3.40342
15 -3.38839
15 -3.37321
15 -3.3579
15 -3.34245
15 -3.32687
15 -3.31114
15 -3.29529
15 -3.27929
15 -3.26316
15 -3.2469
15 -3.2305
15 -3.21397
15 -3.1973
15 -3.18051
15 -3.16357
15 -3.14651
15 -3.12931
15 -3.11198
15 -3.09452
15 -3.07692
15 -3.0592
15 -3.04134
15 -3.02335
15 -3.00523
15 -2.98698
15 -2.9686
15 -2.95009
15 -2.93144
15 -2.91267
15 -2.89377
15 -2.87473
15 -2.85557
15 -2.83626
15 -2.81677
15 -2.79709
15 -2.77721
15 -2.75713
15 -2.73687
15 -2.71641
15 -2.69575
15 -2.67491
15 -2.65387
15 -2.63264
15 -2.61121
15 -2.58959
15 -2.56778
15 -2.54578
15 -2.52358
15 -2.50119
15 -2.47861
15 -2.45583
15 -2.43287
15 -2.4097
15 -2.38635
15 -2.3628
15 -2.33906
15 -2.31512
15 -2.29099
15 -2.26666
15 -2.24214
15 -2.21742
15 -2.19251
15 -2.1674
15 -2.14209
15 -2.11658
15 -2.09088
15 -2.06498
15 -2.03888
15 -2.01258
15 -1.98608
15 -1.95937
15 -1.93247
15 -1.90536
15 -1.87805
15 -1.85053
15 -1.82281
15 -1.79488
15 -1.76675
15 -1.7384
15 -1.70985
15 -1.68109
15 -1.65211
15 -1.62294
15 -1.59361
15 -1.56413
15 -1.53452
15 -1.50475
15 -1.47484
15 -1.44478
15 -1.41456
15 -1.3842
15 -1.35368
15 -1.323
15 -1.29217
15 -1.26117
15 -1.23002
15 -1.1987
15 -1.16722
15 -1.13557
15 -1.10375
15 -1.07177
15 -1.03961
15 -1.00727
15 -0.974763
15 -0.942076
15 -0.909208
15 -0.876157
15 -0.842922
15 -0.8095
15 -0.775889
15 -0.742087
15 -0.708091
15 -0.673899
15 -0.639509
15 -0.604918
15 -0.570123
15 -0.535123
15 -0.499914
15 -0.464494
15 -0.428861
15 -0.393011
15 -0.356941
15 -0.32065
15 -0.284134
15 -0.24739
15 -0.210415
15 -0.173207
15 -0.135762
15 -0.0980763
15 -0.0601479
15 -0.0219731
15 0.0238143
15 0.0918672
15 0.137673
15 0.175878
15 0.213852
15 0.251598
15 0.289118
15 0.326416
15 0.363494
15 0.400356
15 0.437004
15 0.47344
15 0.509669
15 0.545691
15 0.581511
15 0.617129
15 0.65255
15 0.687775
15 0.722807
15 0.757648
15 0.792301
15 0.826767
15 0.86105
15 0.895151
15 0.929072
15 0.962817
15 0.996386
15 1.02978
15 1.06301
15 1.09606
15 1.12895
15 1.16168
15 1.19424
15 1.22663
15 1.25887
15 1.29096
15 1.32288
15 1.35465
15 1.38627
15 1.41774
15 1.44906
15 1.48023
15 1.51126
15 1.54214
15 1.57287
15 1.60347
15 1.63393
15 1.66424
15 1.69442
15 1.72447
15 1.75438
15 1.78414
15 1.81372
15 1.84308
15 1.87225
15 1.90121
15 1.92997
15 1.95853
15 1.98689
15 2.01506
15 2.04302
15 2.07079
15 2.09835
15 2.12573
15 2.15291
15 2.17989
15 2.20668
15 2.23327
15 2.25967
15 2.28588
15 2.3119
15 2.33772
15 2.36335
15 2.38879
15 2.41404
15 2.4391
15 2.48864
15 2.51313
15 2.53742
15 2.56153
15 2.58544
15 2.60917
15 2.6327
15 2.65605
15 2.6792
15 2.70217
15 2.72494
15 2.74752
15 2.76992
15 2.79212
15 2.81413
15 2.83595
15 2.85758
15 2.87901
15 2.90026
15 2.92131
15 2.94217
15 2.96283
15 2.9833
15 3.00358
15 3.02367
15 3.04363
15 3.06346
15 3.08316
15 3.10273
15 3.12217
15 3.14148
15 3.16067
15 3.17973
15 3.19865
15 3.21745
15 3.23612
15 3.25466
15 3.27307
15 3.29134
15 3.30949
15 3.3275
15 3.34539
15 3.36314
15 3.38076
15 3.39824
15 3.41559
15 3.4499
15 3.46685
15 3.48366
15 3.50034
15 3.51688
15 3.53328
15 3.54955
15 3.56568
15 3.58167
15 3.59752
15 3.61323
15 3.6288
15 3.64423
15 3.65952
15 3.67467
16 -3.82315
16 -3.8135
16 -3.80375
16 -3.79391
16 -3.78396
16 -3.77391
16 -3.76377
16 -3.75353
16 -3.7432
16 -3.73277
16 -3.72224
16 -3.71162
16 -3.7009
16 -3.6901
16 -3.67919
16 -3.6682
16 -3.65711
16 -3.64593
16 -3.63466
16 -3.6233
16 -3.61185
16 -3.60031
16 -3.58868
16 -3.57697
16 -3.56516
16 -3.54128
16 -3.52921
16 -3.50481
16 -3.49248
16 -3.46756
16 -3.45492
16 -3.42924
16 -3.4162
16 -3.38971
16 -3.37627
16 -3.34899
16 -3.33516
16 -3.30709
16 -3.29287
16 -3.26403
16 -3.24942
16 -3.21981
16 -3.20482
16 -3.17446
16 -3.15909
16 -3.12798
16 -3.11224
16 -3.08038
16 -3.06427
16 -3.03168
16 -3.0152
16 -2.98187
16 -2.96503
16 -2.93098
16 -2.91377
16 -2.87899
16 -2.86143
16 -2.82593
16 -2.808
16 -2.77179
16 -2.7535
16 -2.73509
16 -2.71657
16 -2.69792
16 -2.67914
16 -2.6602
16 -2.62177
16 -2.60229
16 -2.5628
16 -2.54279
16 -2.50223
16 -2.48168
16 -2.44005
16 -2.41898
16 -2.37629
16 -2.35467
16 -2.31092
16 -2.28878
16 -2.24395
16 -2.22127
16 -2.17538
16 -2.15216
16 -2.10519
16 -2.08144
16 -2.03338
16 -2.00908
16 -1.95993
16 -1.93508
16 -1.88483
16 -1.85943
16 -1.80807
16 -1.7821
16 -1.72961
16 -1.70308
16 -1.64944
16 -1.62234
16 -1.56754
16 -1.53985
16 -1.48395
16 -1.4558
16 -1.3991
16 -1.37055
16 -1.31302
16 -1.28405
16 -1.22568
16 -1.19627
16 -1.13703
16 -1.10718
16 -1.04702
16 -1.01671
16 -0.955609
16 -0.92482
16 -0.862749
16 -0.831463
16 -0.768383
16 -0.736584
16 -0.672456
16 -0.640123
16 -0.574909
16 -0.542023
16 -0.47568
16 -0.442219
16 -0.374703
16 -0.340644
16 -0.27191
16 -0.23723
16 -0.202336
16 -0.167228
16 -0.131901
16 -0.0963523
16 -0.0605796
16 -0.0245797
16 0.0116507
16 0.054991
16 0.119126
16 0.162484
16 0.198743
16 0.234786
16 0.270616
16 0.306236
16 0.341647
16 0.376855
16 0.41186
16 0.446665
16 0.481274
16 0.515689
16 0.549912
16 0.583945
16 0.617792
16 0.651455
16 0.684936
16 0.718237
16 0.751361
16 0.78431
16 0.817086
16 0.849691
16 0.882128
16 0.914398
16 0.946504
16 0.978448
16 1.01023
16 1.04186
16 1.07332
16 1.10464
16 1.1358
16 1.16681
16 1.19767
16 1.22839
16 1.25895
16 1.28938
16 1.31966
16 1.3498
16 1.37981
16 1.40967
16 1.4394
16 1.469
16 1.49846
16 1.52779
16 1.55699
16 1.58607
16 1.61501
16 1.64384
16 1.67253
16 1.70111
16 1.72955
16 1.75781
16 1.78588
16 1.81377
16 1.84146
16 1.86898
16 1.8963
16 1.92345
16 1.9504
16 1.97718
16 2.00377
16 2.03019
16 2.05642
16 2.08247
16 2.10834
16 2.13403
16 2.15955
16 2.18488
16 2.21004
16 2.23502
16 2.25982
16 2.28445
16 2.3089
16 2.33317
16 2.35727
16 2.38119
16 2.40494
16 2.42852
16 2.45191
16 2.47514
16 2.49818
16 2.52106
16 2.54376
16 2.56628
16 2.58863
16 2.61081
16 2.63281
16 2.65463
16 2.67628
16 2.69776
16 2.71906
16 2.74018
16 2.76113
16 2.7819
16 2.8025
16 2.82292
16 2.84316
16 2.86323
16 2.88311
16 2.90282
16 2.92236
16 2.94178
16 2.96108
16 2.98026
16 2.99932
16 3.01827
16 3.0371
16 3.05581
16 3.07441
16 3.09288
16 3.11124
16 3.12948
16 3.1476
16 3.16561
16 3.18349
16 3.20125
16 3.2189
16 3.23642
16 3.25383
16 3.27111
16 3.28827
16 3.30531
16 3.32223
16 3.33902
16 3.3557
16 3.37225
16 3.38867
16 3.40497
16 3.42115
16 3.4372
16 3.45313
16 3.46892
16 3.4846
16 3.50014
16 3.51556
16 3.53084
16 3.546
16 3.56103
16 3.57593
16 3.59069
16 3.60533
16 3.61983
16 3.63419
16 3.64843
16 3.66253
16 3.67649
16 3.69032
16 3.70401
16 3.71756
16 3.73097
16 3.74425
16 3.75744
16 3.77054
16 3.78356
16 3.79649
16 3.80933
16 3.82209
16 3.83475
16 3.84733
16 3.85982
16 3.8722
16 3.88452
16 3.89674
16 3.90887
16 3.9209
16 3.93284
16 3.94469
16 3.95645
16 3.96811
16 3.97967
16 3.99114
16 4.00251
16 4.01379
16 4.02497
16 4.03605
16 4.04703
16 4.05791
16 4.0687
16 4.07938
16 4.08996
16 4.10043
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, but this is too little information to help. On StackOverflow we expect to see at least a minimum of own research effort. What have to tried so far? Please edit your question: add the data (as text not as image) and the code you've tried so far. To which function you want to fit your data? And please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edit my question. Can you help me please

Comment: It looks like the first column of data has been truncated to an integer.  Could there be an error in the program that generated this file?

Comment: There is no error. The first colomn represent the time t

Comment: @mati In your original question you showed the full data as image. How do you want to fit a function to _this_ data? Ideally you have some theory or model behind your fit function. Or at least you want to show some linear or quadratic,etc. behaviour. But if I look at your (original) data graph, this could be anything. Sorry, with this data and little information I can't help.